# activiz 64 bits control

Tags: 64-bit, vtk, rendercontrol

I've installed Activiz 5.8.0 on my project (I installed both 32 and 64 bits versions through the Nuget package manager).

I can import to the toolbox only the 32 bits RenderWindowControl component of Kitware.VTK.dll, when I try the 64 bits version it doesn't work (I can't even import it to the toolbox).

I'm using VS2012 64 bits edition.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2008 and I know there are some issues with the form designer in 64 bits, but if you get your references right you should be able to compile your application in release mode using the activiz 64 bit. For debug stick to the 32 bit version.